# Rails find_by_sql to find a self referential subset of the model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, self-join

I have a simple relationship:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_organization, class_name: 'Organization'
end
```

So an organization can be related to another organization that acts as its parent.

I'm looking for a way to return all of the `Organization` instances that are currently acting as parents.

Basically, find all the organizations whose id is referenced in `Organization#parent_organization_id` column in an efficient way, so I can setup a scope like:

`Organization.parent`, which would return all of the Organizations that function as parents.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Organization.where("id in (?)", Organization.pluck(:parent_organization_id))
```

And then you can use that as a scope to make usage easier:

```
scope :parent, where("id in (?)", Organization.pluck(:parent_organization_id))
```